# How to Fetch Values from JTable and add to database. Jtable and db columns are different

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, database-connection

I want to fetch values from Jtable and then want to add them in database. but i am getting error **"No value specified for parameter 2"** . and what is the replacement of `pstmt.setString(j+1, (String)o);` in case float and int values.

Here is code. Screen shots are below

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `purchases`(`Pr_ID`,`Model`, `Name`, `Purchase_Price`, `Sale_Price`, `Quantity`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    Object o = model.getValueAt(i, j);
                    System.out.println("object from table is  : " +o);
                    pstmt.setString(j+1, (String)o);
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                    pstmt.clearParameters();
                }
             }
```

Jtable Screen Shot
[image]

Database Picture:
[image]

**Note: Pur_ID is Primary key that is auto incremented. and Pr_ID is foreign key**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "No value specified for parameter 2"

You have only assigned the data of the first column to the PreparedStatement

```
pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt.clearParameters();
```

Don't execute the above statements inside the column loop. You are tying to execute the update on the database once for every column.

You should only execute the statement once, after all the values have been assigned to the statement. That is, once for each row.

Comment: I need a one more solution if u can help please. 

pstmt.setString(j+1, (String)o); This is for only string. but my values are float and integer also. what is the replacement of it ?